# GroupBy - Get TotalCount

Tags: c#, group-by

I have data like this

data

```
1 1 2 2 2 2 2 blank/ null 1 1 3 3 4 4 4 blank/ null blank/ null
```

Trying to get the base (total non blank rows) and percent column along with frequency.

So far Achieved to get this

```
Column  Count
 1        4
 2        5
 3        2 
 4        3
```

With this code

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>(xx), (row, l) => new Group { Column = row, Count = l.Count() })
```

I am trying groupby to get output something like this

```
Column  Count           Base      Percent
 1       4               14      28.57142857
 2       5               14      35.71428571
 3       2               14      14.28571429
 4       3               14      21.42857143
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps

1. Filter out unwanted entries (nulls)
2. Get the total count
3. Group your data
4. Project the data to your desired result

Like this

```
var data = new int?[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, null, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, null, null };
var filteredData = data.Where(x => x != null);
var totalCount = filteredData.Count();
var groups = filteredData.GroupBy(x => x);
var result = groups.Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count(), Percent = x.Count() * 100.0 / totalCount });
```

Note: a group is a collection of the grouped items plus a key. The key is whatever your chose to group by. In this example, the key is an int. And because the group is a collection you can do stuff like `.Count()` on it.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find that it helped you.